# d3 SVG not displaying on mobile (iOS)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, datepicker, leaflet

I have an app that is working fine on desktop Chrome.  It's a leaflet map, and an SVG layer of "events" is appended to the map dynamically based on the date selected in a calendar (I'm using d3.js and datepicker.js). However, in Chrome and Safari on iOS, the SVG layer is not displaying. Here's the (much abbreviated) code:

```
//Build the datepicker using datepicker.js
const picker = datepicker(document.querySelector('#datepicker'), {

  // Get selected date from datepicker
    onSelect: function(instance) {
    
    var instanceSplit = instance.dateSelected.toString().split(" " ,4)
    var instanceClean = instanceSplit.toString().replace(/,/g, ' ')
    selectedDate = instanceClean
    update()
       
    },
});

// render d3 svg
var events = mapG.selectAll("circle")
    .data(allSFEvents)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", 'events')
    .style("fill", '#ffba00')
    .attr("r", 7.5)
    .style("display", initialDateMatch)
    .style("pointer-events", "all")

// Display only events on today's date
function initalDateMatch(data){
     //Do some stuff to get if today's date matches event date
     if (todaysDate === data.dateFormatted) {
        return 'inline'
        } else {
        return 'none'
        }
     }

 //Check if selected matches the "date" property of data, if so, return "inline" 
 function dateMatch(data){

     if (selectedDate === data.dateFormatted) {
        return 'inline'
        } else {
        return 'none'
        }
     }

//Pass in the returned value above when new date is selected in order to filter points
function update(value) {

d3.selectAll(".events")
    .style("display", dateMatch);
}
```

This works perfectly on desktop, so I know the code is functional as is.  On mobile, none of the SVG points show up on the map.  The only way I can get them to show up is if I change this line:

```
.style("display", initialDateMatch)
```

to:

```
.style("display", "inline")
```

So, I know the issue is not iOS ability to render SVG, bad links with data, etc. etc.  What can I try next?